# How to use environment variables when updating a react native app via codepush?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have a react native app where I store the android/ios app version in config.js file in the root directory. Now I want to use the codepush to dynamically update some changes which involve using variables from the config.js file. Now here is the catch, if I push those changes via codepush then the config.js file will be changed as well and pushed along with the latest js bundle. Is there any way I can not include certain files in the codepush bundle while deploying the new changes?